# How to change the color sliders to a color wheel like picker on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I've checked all the options and I can't seem to change the sliders into a wheel (or rather a square) and being super new to Photoshop I don't know how to do it and couldn't even phrase it properly to look it up on Google.

What I'm trying to say is that, I can't seem to get my Color window to look like the regular color wheel that one would normally use on Photoshop, mine only goes from one range of a slider to another and I've checked that little list thing and those are still just sliders.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There's no "color wheel" unless you mean the color picker wheel, however there are "color cubes". Can you post a screen shot of the problem?

Comment: You can not. You could try to buy some external plugin but default photoshop has no color wheel.

Comment: Photoshop CC 2019 has a color wheel, q.v. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkJvvK8ufDw) for how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Photoshop CC includes [Adobe Color Themes](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adobe-color-themes.html)

Window → Extensions → Adobe Color Themes

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I'm reading your intent correctly, it's the first pref on the first Prefs pane...

It defaults to Adobe, but your OS standard picker should be the other option.

[image]

I'm on Mac, so I don't know what the Windows default colour-picker looks like, but I can have either...

Adobe

[image]

or Apple

[image]

Comment: The other option is Windows and changing that didnt change it to a wheel for me, what I want is for it to be a color wheel and not a slider

Comment: I don't know what the Windows default colour-picker looks like, I'm on Mac - but they are your two options, Adobe or "system".

Comment: I see, but still it doesnt get me a wheel

Comment: I presume that depends on what the Windows default picker is. I've never seen it, sorry. I added examples to the answer, for Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Windows has no colour picker tool installed by default, but there are many colour-picker apps you can download, often for free.

Comment: ahh, ok - weird ... but thanks ;)

Comment: @BillyKerr It does actually have a default colour picker, but it's not a separate program. It's best known as the custom colour picker from `mspaint.exe`, but it crops up in Microsoft Word and some versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

[You can also use MagicPicker Photoshop color wheel](http://anastasiy.com/colorwheel) which is an external plugin:

[image: MagicPicker color wheel mode in Photoshop (screenshots)]

I'm using it personally for many years since older Photoshop CS4 but it supports Photoshop CC and CC 2018 (the most recent Photoshop version).

Considering other options integrated into operating system I think it's a better alternative, because when you use integrated color pickers they tend to make Photoshop lose keyboard/mouse focus.